# How to overcome the frustration while you are developing demanding techniques?

Tags: guitar, technique, flamenco

I'm practicing Flamenco guitar and I'm concentrating a **LOT** on the technique.
Flamenco is so demanding on the right hand, techniques like tremolo, rasgueados, alzapua ...

It is hard to play flamenco without having decent techniques, this could lead to frustrating.

Should I concentrate on other things? how to overcome the frustration while you are developing demanding techniques?

Comment: Something that helps me is once a week, I just play - no practicing specifics, just fun.

Comment: I believe you mean "frustration" instead of 'frustrating"

Comment: It's important to distinguish between emotional frustration and physical difficulty. The balance may change suddenly and this requires self-awareness. If it's "merely physical". you can charge through just a little further: ten more reps! five more! ... But if you're getting upset about "not-getting" something, stop. Play something fun. Try it later from a different angle. <br><br> Emotions affect your chemistry which affects your muscle response and your nervous system. Negative emotions will cause bad performance. And then practice becomes a chore, not play.

Comment: I just started but I've found this tutorial very helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77ScJgcOhZ0 I just about have the first rhythm down in about an hour.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some professions are very much about knowledge and the ability to exercise that knowledge, others are more about skill.

Music is very much about skill, and the thing with skills is that they take a long time to develop. With the exception of people with a natural aptitude, it takes a lot of time and patience -- there is just no way around it.

So what can you do to combat this sort of frustration:

- Above all, be patient.
- Work on the techniques in isolation. Find or invent exercises that target each of these techniques individually and start slow. Then maybe combine ones when you get good at them
- Practice each one a little each day, don't get stuck on one.
- Understand, that some days, 'It just ain't gonna happen'. Also, other days will be better   -- it goes back and forth. If it isn't happening, don't force it, breath, practice it a little bit slowly and move on.
- Use mental practice, it is easier to do things if you can visualize what they look like, and also "visualize" how they *feel* and sound.
- Take lots of breaks when you practice these techniques.
- Focus on being relaxed while you practice. Maybe re-evaluate your caffeine intake if you find yourself raging.

Eventually, with good practice, and good teachers, these techniques will come. It will probably take you years -- enjoy the journey and don't force it.

Comment: +1: Agree. Work on easier repertoire while drilling the techniques that give you trouble in isolation as part of your routine. Also, I'm a huge fan of (at least on piano) practicing difficult technique at _incredibly_ slow tempos to get every little thing absolutely perfect while using more of your brain at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Additional to Kyle Brand's ideas, which are clear and to the point, I always keep in my head the statements from Steve Vai on 'How to be Successful':

I always find it inspiring and puts me back in the mood to keep practicing and overcome the frustration.

I think the statement that resonates in my head the strongest is 'Whenever you get discouraged, go to the Big Picture...'

Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

[**This question**](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/i-need-help-getting-out-of-my-scalar-rut) on how to get out of a rut has some answers that may be appropriate. Not necessarily the specifics, but the general guidance on trying something new and avoiding the frustration points.

As @Kyle says - it's all about time, patience and practice, and you just need to make it easy on yourself those times when it just isn't flowing - maybe don't take 5arx's comment too literally on that link, but sometimes relaxing with a glass of wine could work:-)