# How can I learn to play vibraphone like Gary Burton?

Tags: learning, jazz, books

I play jazz vibraphone. I'm fan of Gary Burton's playing.

I'm looking for books or online ressources (solo transcriptions, technical analysis of his style, etc...) on Gary Burton or which could help me in understanding his play and getting there myself. (Pointers to good stuff related to other players are welcome too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to [make your own solo transcriptions](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/i-need-help-getting-out-of-my-scalar-rut/2062#2062).  Get some software that slows down music without changing its pitch, and use it to transcribe your favorite Gary Burton solos.  Like most things, when you do it yourself it's much harder and slower, but you also learn much more deeply and completely.  If you simply want to play Gary Burton solos, then someone else's transcriptions are fine; if you truly want to understand his play and get there yourself, you've got to do the hard work yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with taking the free Berklee Music course Gary Burton teaches on www.coursera.org - Introduction to Jazz Improvisation. Next session starts in 6 days. I also just realized this is a really old question, so hopefully the OP is still around and has progressed in his jazz playing skills :)